# Plural Word PHP if number is bigger than 2

Tags: php

I have a code that counts the number of companies. I would like to add word company or companies if number is bigger >

0 companies
1 company
2 companies
.... and so on

The code I use is as follows:

```
echo $activeCompanies = Model_Company::search(array("count_only"=>true));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [function switching between singular and plural?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728933/function-switching-between-singular-and-plural)

Answer (score 5):

I usually use something like this

```
echo "{$activeCompanies} compan".($activeCompanies == 1 ? "y" : "ies");
```

See the following link for more information on ternary operators: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: This is a great answer